# CSS and JS files not uploading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm uploading a site that I built using a template from templatemo. http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_367_shoes
I modified it in Dreamweaver CS6 to put my images in the slideshow, background, pages and links,browsing it locally everything looks ok, but when I uploaded it to the server it seems that the index page doesnt recognized the CSS, JS, and  image files related to it.
the 3 of them has its own folder as the original, I also tried to put them in the root folder and update the index, but it doesn't read it either.the website that I'm building is http://dogodesign.eu/index.html
the index page uses several scripts:
    templatemo_style.css,
    nivo-slider.css,
    jquery-1.4.3.min.js,
    jquery.min.js,
    ddsmoothmenu.js,
    ddsmoothmenu.css,

I need help as this is my first website.

thanks!

Comment: Can you show folder structure as image?

Comment: try ctrl-f5 in browser.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be  permissions problem on your server. Your webserver directory should have `www-data` group or should have `755` permissions on it.